# When has Lex Luthor been a Cardinal or Pope?

Tags: story-identification, dc, superman, lex-luthor

I came across this miniature of Lex Luthor for the Heroclix board game.

[image]

Most information I have been able to find about that picture is actually [on this page](http://www.mysterious-stranger.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3318).

I don't know to which comic book, series or *elseworlds* it belongs, but it looks like Lex Luthor is sporting red robes and sitting in a very fancy "throne", much like a cardinal (Shall he had been wearing white, I would have suggested "pope").

As I said I could not find much by googling "Lex Luthor cardinal" or "Lex Luthor pope". Could anyone tell me if this figurine actually resembles a story arc and if so which one?

Comment: Have you tried Googling  "Lex Luthor snuggie"?

Comment: @JohnSensebe, I just did and I got [this](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8f/26/53/8f265380d03ea19ddac18c534895a87a.jpg)

Comment: that's not Lex. That's Magneto.

Comment: Hm, not's not what Cardinals wear. I think you're thinking of the red cassock, which is more fitted and buttons all the way down the front. Also, he'd have a skullcap.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## In *Action Comics* #23, Luthor's debut

[image]

Luthor debuted in this early issue of *Action Comics*, shortly after Superman himself, as a kind of Friar Tuck-like mad genius.  Not a Cardinal or Pope.

**Interesting fact:** In this issue, Luthor's vehicle of choice is a dirigible.  He ends up crashing it.

Comment: Is that why he's "Luthor"?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai I believe you're thinking of [Luther](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Luther).

Comment: @jpmc26 I am, that's why I asked. But Lex spells it "Luthor," see the OP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm a little bit disappointed he is not a cardinal, though. I was more misled by that throne than the robe itself. I though this Luthorwas part of a _Elseworld_ were Luthor was a ecclesiastic of some kind, ala "Holy Terror" story of Batman. Anyway, then you again for your answer. Was very interesting to learn this.